# Convert point to line

Tags: qgis, vector, convert, point, line

I recently completed a long bike trip and used a GPS to gather data during the ride, including average speed and elevation loss/gain. I imported the data into QGIS. These data were gathered per mile, and I have them in a point shapefile with the points being the mile marker where the data is stored.

I want to convert these points into a line file that displays different values for each of the mile markers. I am trying to do this using the Points To One plugin but am having trouble, it does not recognize anything from the attribute table.

Is this type of conversion possible, and is it even possible to display different values in a single line shapefile?

Comment: A single line can only have one set of attributes, so you have to split up the line at every vertex point.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pull a polyline shapefile through my GPS into QGIS, and with that I was able to construct a line using the points and the Reconstruct Line function. It was a bit messy but ended up suiting my needs.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this tool will do what you are asking:

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=12702

it will allow you to create seperate line features between the points, i think it will pull the point attributes through, but if it doesnt you would join the points to the line to pull the attributes through.

here is similar article from here: [Converting Points to Lines in ArcGIS AND retaining attributes of both start and end points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61032/converting-points-to-lines-in-arcgis-and-retaining-attributes-of-both-start-and)

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add in the OP that I am using QGIS, so I may not be able to use this tool, but I'll see what I can get from it.

Comment: Do you have information on the sequence of points, maybe in some attribute there is info about this ? If yes than select in Points To One "sort verticles by" and pick attribute with sequence number.

Comment: try this then http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/12/30/qgis-plugin-of-the-week-points-to-paths/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92751/draw-lines-from-points-in-qgis  ... it may create one line from the start point to the end, but you can write a script to go from point to point creating line segments and copying over attributes.